# Does Islam believe in the revelation at Sinai

Tags: torah, comparative-religions

Does Islam believe in the revelation at Sinai according to the Bible?

Comment: God did not reject the Jews altogether, but [most of the disobedient Jews](http://quran.com/4/150-160) for their disbelief incurred the wrath of God except a [few](http://quran.com/4/155) and those few are [safe and need not worry](http://quran.com/2/62)

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser but why should they be held accountable for disbelief? what evidence is there that God rejected them, etc?

Comment: Here plz [go ahead](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/anti-semitism/koranjews.html) in your leisure,

Comment: Your first question shows zero research effort. [A simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=islam+quran+moses+revelation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) can easily lead you to answers. You are also asking new questions in the comments. Either incorporate those new questions to your main post, or post them as separate questions.

Comment: @infatuated didn't find any evidence in those searches. just statements from the koran damning the jews for not believing. my question is what evidence is there that God made a change of plan. real evidence. not something one has take on belief. after all, the bible itself says not to change it.

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser the plan setout in the 5 books of Moses. have you ever read it??

Comment: I don't fully understand what your question is except that what you're asking is a new question which warrants a separate post. So post it as a new question with adequate elaboration.

Comment: @infatuated so if i understand correctly, according to islam a jew will be punished for not believing in the koran despite that there is no evidence that God changed the original plan. correct? hope i am not being disrespectful and thank you for your time

Comment: As I said, your questions can not be properly treated in comments, for there are certain ambiguities. First "the change in plan" thesis requires extensive explanation. Also, I'm not sure what kind of evidence you are looking for! Some Quranic references are already provided by servant-of-Wiser. Are you looking for historical evidences? Please clarify these points in your main question. Then, I may write an answer of my own that can hopefully help you understand Islam better. And no, your questions sound respectful and genuine, and that's why you're getting attention. :)

Comment: Please ask a separate question asking your second part, "What evidence if at all is there that God rejected the Jews or considers that Jews are disbelivers and add something like where in Qur'an does it tell that Jews have to convert to Islam to be saved" or something like that in another question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Islam believes in revelation at Sinai . Allah says in the Quraan verse 15 chapter 79 "   Has there reached you the story of Moses? -
( 16 )   When his Lord called to him in the sacred valley of Tuwa,"=Sinai 
 This is the evidence that there was a revelation there .

Allah (god) did not reject the Jews. They are the ones who rejected His message when He sent Jesus later and then Muhammad as the last messenger. Allah criticized them that they rejected the message of God because the messenger was not Jew. They should have accepted the trues message from the one God no matter who brings it.

Comment: dont see how this answers the question. i'm looking for evidence. i.e. why should they be held accountable for not believing. what evidence was there that they should have believed there was a change of plan. thank you.

Comment: "not to follow anyone who comes to change its precepts..." gud, u caught the point,,, neither Jesus (pbuh) nor Muhammad (pbuh) neither changed its precepts not diminished its value&&& by following Torah perfectly, I mean to say, act upon it perfectly, don't act on a part of it, & leave a part thereof, act upon it strictly,,,, & love God & fear him & believe in the day of resurrection...! & a "God bless u" would suffice. @m.r.

Comment: We actly? If it's an evidence from the Quraan, there are many. And it's not against the Jew in general, it's only against the disbelievers whether they Jews or not.

Comment: If you're looking for a logical evidence, think about it like this : was Moses the first and only prophet from God? No.. Are the Jew the only people God created? No.. Allah sent many messengers before and after Moses until the last prophet Muhammad. All of them have the same principle and call to the same principle. So disbelieving in one of them, is a disbelief in all of them.. The Jew when they rejected jesus and Muhammad, they have actually rejected Moses and rejected God himself

Comment: @SaraElkilany but God told the jews in the torah to reject anyone who comes to change the torah, i.e. to add or detract from the commandments there. obviously He has foresight as to who will come in the future

Comment: Yeah. God told the Muslims the same in the Quraan, to reject anyone who comes to change the Torah, He actually commanded the Jews and Christians to continue abiding by their books and to fulfill what He asked them to do there. Allah Says in the Quraan Chapter 5 (( 43 )   But how is it that they come to you for judgement while they have the Torah, in which is the judgement of Allah? Then they turn away, [even] after that; but those are not [in fact] believers.) u ..etc until verse 48.

Comment: Where Allah says: (And We have revealed to you, [O Muhammad], the Book in truth, confirming that which preceded it of the Scripture and as a criterion over it. So judge between them by what Allah has revealed and do not follow their inclinations away from what has come to you of the truth. )  So this means that all the books Torah and Quraan came with the same principle because they came from the same source and it is clear in the Quraan that Allah had told the Jews about Mohammad before, but some of their scholars hid that truth from the Torah and altered the word of Allah.

Comment: That's why He is asking them to go back to the real Torah which will guide them to believe in the Quraan. And in another verse in the same Surah Allah says the reason he is sending another prophet :( 19 ) O People of the Scripture, there has come to you Our Messenger to make clear to you [the religion] after a period [of suspension] of messengers, lest you say, "There came not to us any bringer of good tidings or a warner." But there has come to you a bringer of good tidings and a warner.This Chapter (Almaidah No 5) is full of verses addressed to the Jews and the people of the Book generally.

Comment: I am sorry if I a am bringing all my evidence to you from the Quraan, not from Torah itself.. Becuase the Quraan is the authentic word of Allah while the current Torah has been altered and changed

Answer (score 0):

I'll directly jump to the 2nd question as others have answered the first.

> what evidence is there that **God has rejected the Jews?**

I understand your usage of the word in general and asking such a question as what evidence is there that God rejected 'the Jews' altogether. This line (rumor) got compiled as a notion has arisen due to many verses of hatred against Jews present in the Qur'an. Here is a [list](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/anti-semitism/koranjews.html) (from a Jewish site itself where you can trust) which lists out all the places where Jews are mentioned (or referred to) in the Qur'an.

That general notion of "God <strike>rejected</strike> *cursed* the Jews for their disbelief/bad behavior/not abiding by what was given to them/not being observant Jews/changing words in the scriptures/etc. etc. is because many out of the set of the Jews did that in the past, and who knows are still doing today out there. Hence, it says in the Qur'an that Allah has sealed their hearts (forever). Read [more...](http://quran.com/5/78-80)

**But**, I don't think Lord God can be biased. So, if you take some time to read the Qur'an or especially in complete context in the places where Jews are being referred to, you can find that still there are verses which have a positive opinion on the ***very few Jews left out there** (**May be like you**, who are exploring the reasons for that blame and doing something to not repeat the same mistakes again as that like of the ancestors)*. Infact, all those favors which God favored on Jews, were out of the mercy and love which he bestowed on Jews, but *many of them couldn't withhold that*.

The reason why Qur'an came down was because to guide today's humanity.

The reason why Allah sent down Torah was because he could guide the children of Israel of the time span of ~1300 BC to ~1 A.D. (Until time of Jesus (pbuh)).

But, today, God gives out two options for them. Either to [follow what was revealed to you](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24343/was-torah-the-first-complete-shariah) i.e. on Moses (pbuh) or..... you can continue with the book which got revealed recently fresh a new.

If you ask what evidence is their that God still loves Jews?

There are a lot of evidences that God will love Jews conditional if they behave right.

> And if only they had acted according to the Taurat (Torah), the Injeel (Gospel), and what has (now) been sent down to them from their Lord (the Quran), they would surely have gotten provision from above them and from underneath their feet. There are from among them people who are on the right course (i.e. they act on the revelation and believe in Prophet Muhammad SAW like 'Abdullah bin Salam), *but many of them do evil deeds*. (Qur'an 5:66)
>
> Surely, **those who believe** (in the Oneness of Allah, in His Messenger Muhammad SAW and all that was revealed to him from Allah), **those who are the Jews** and the Sabians and the Christians, - whosoever believed in Allah and the Last Day, **and worked righteousness**, *on them shall be no fear, nor shall they grieve.* (Qur'an 5:69)

Hatred develops, only if people do acts which lead to it. Why would people hate if no one did anything wrong at the first place?

God hated because the previous generations of Jews did not obey God. (*except but a few* who knows). But, if a person asks forgiveness and believes and does righteous good deeds, then why would God reject any person on this planet?

If you're interested as to how the picture of Jews is presented, how did they do wrong things, how were they saved from the bad Pahroah etc. you might be interested to read the chapters like 2, 5 etc. from the [Qur'an](http://quran.com/) to get a complete picture.

So, to conclude, if you simply ask this way, *Why did "God reject the Jews"*, I could say, there are no evidences in the Qur'an which say that.

May the creator guide us all.

---

<sub>What is (pbuh)? Here you [go](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/24362/11938).</sub>

Comment: thank you but jesus was not a prophet. he claimed to be God which is obviously crazy. i dont see any evidence here except for quotes from the koran which is a circular argument.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely. Jews believe that:

> God spoke to you from the midst of the fire, you were hearing the sound of words, but you were not seeing a form, only a sound. He told you of His covenant, instructing you to keep the Ten Commandments, and He inscribed them on two stone tablets.' (Deut.4:9-13)

However, in Islam we only believe that Moses selected 70 of the best of people so they go with him and apologize to Allah for worshipping the golden Calf. In the Quran, Allah says:

> واختار موسى قومه سبعين رجلا لميقاتنا فلما اخذتهم الرجفة قال رب لو شئت اهلكتهم من قبل واياي اتهلكنا بما فعل السفهاء منا ان هي الا فتنتك تضل بها من تشاء وتهدي من تشاء انت ولينا فاغفر لنا وارحمنا وانت خير الغافرين
>
> And Moses chose from his people seventy men for Our appointment. And when the earthquake seized them, he said, "My Lord, if You had willed, You could have destroyed them before and me [as well]. Would You destroy us for what the foolish among us have done? This is not but Your trial by which You send astray whom You will and guide whom You will. You are our Protector, so forgive us and have mercy upon us; and You are the best of forgivers.[7:155]

A translator, Ibn Katheer further expands on this by [saying](http://quran.com/search?q=%D8%B3%D9%8A%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%A1):

> روي مثل هذا عن عباس وبعض السلف. وقال محمد بن إسحاق: اختار موسى من بني إسرائيل سبعين رجلاً: الخِّير فالخير، وقال انطلقوا إلى اللّه فتوبوا إليه مما صنعتم، وسلوه التوبة على من تركتم وراءكم من قومكم، صوموا وتطهروا وطهروا ثيابكم، فخرج بهم إلى طور سيناء لمقيات وقّته له ربه، وكان لا يأتيه إلا بإذن منه وعلم، فقال له السبعون - فيما ذكر لي حين صنعوا ما أمرهم به وخرجوا معه للقاء ربه - لموسى، اطلب لنا نسمع كلام ربنا، فقال: أفعل، فلما دنا موسى من الجبل وقع عليه عمود الغمام حتى تغشى الجبل كله، ودنا موسى فدخل فيه وقال للقوم: ادنوا، وكان موسى إذا كلمه اللّه وقع على جبهته نور ساطع لا يستطيع أحد من بني آدم أن ينظر إليه فضرب دونه بالحجاب، ودنا القوم حتى إذا دخلوا في الغمام، وقعوا سجوداً فسمعوه وهو يكلم موسى يأمره وينهاه افعل ولا تفعل، فلما فرغ إليه من أمره وانكشف عن موسى الغمام، فأقبل إليهم فقالوا يا موسى: {لن نؤمن لك حتى نرى اللّه جهرة فأخذتهم الرجفة} وهي الصاعقة فالتقت أرواحهم فماتوا جميعاً، فقام موسى يناشد ربه ويدعوه ويرغب إليه ويقول: {رب لو شئت أهلكتهم من قبل وإياي} قد سفهوا، أفتهلك من ورائي بني إسرائيل؟
>
> Muhammad bin Ishaq said, "Musa chose seventy of the best men from the Children of Israel. He said to them, 'Go to the meeting with Allah and repent for what you committed. Beg His forgiveness for those of your people whom you left behind. Fast, purify yourselves and clean your clothes.' So, he went with them to Mount Tur in Sinai for the meeting place and time designated by his Lord. He went there only with the leave and knowledge of Allah. According to what has been mentioned to me, when the seventy did what he ordered them to do, and went with him to the meeting of Musa with his Lord, they said, 'Request that we may also hear the words of our Lord.' So he replied, 'I shall.' When Musa approached the mountain it became completely covered with columns of clouds, Musa approached it and entered in them. He said to the people, 'Approach.' But when Allah spoke to Musa, his cloak was surrounded by a brilliant light which no human could bear to look at, so below him a barrier was placed and the people approached. When they entered the cloud they fell prostrate and they heard Him while he was speaking to Musa, commanding him and forbidding him, saying what to do and what not to do. When He completed commanding him, and removed the cloud from Musa, he faced the people and they said, `O Musa! We will not believe in you unless we see Allah directly.' So the thunder shook them, their souls were captured and they all died. At the end Musa kept praying to Allah until he forgave them and brought them back to life.

In regards to your second question, Allah never rejected the Jews as a matter of fact Jew and Christians who believed in Allah and their messengers are all going to Heaven Inshala.